# Python Memory error solutions if permanent access is required

Tags: python, memory, python-2.7

first, I am aware of the amount of Python memory error questions on SO, but so far, none has matched my use case.

I am currently trying to parse a bunch of textfiles (~6k files with ~30 GB) and store each unique word. Yes, I am building a wordlist, no I am not planning on doing evil things with it, it is for the university.

I implemented the list of found words as a set (created with `words = set([])`, used with `words.add(word)`) and I am just adding every found word to it, considering that the set mechanics should remove all duplicates.

This means that I need permanent access to the whole set for this to work (Or at least I see no alternative, since the whole list has to be checked for duplicates on every insert).

Right now, I am running into `MemoryError` about 25% through, when it uses about 3.4 GB of my RAM. I am on a Linux 32bit, so I know where that limitation comes from, and my PC only has 4 Gigs of RAM, so even 64 bit would not help here.

I know that the complexity is probably terrible (Probably O(n) on each insert, although I don't know how Python sets are implemented (trees?)), but it is still (probably) faster and (definitly) more memory efficient than adding each word to a primitive list and removing duplicates afterwards.

Is there any way to get this to run? I expect about 6-10 GB of unique words, so using my current RAM is out of the question, and upgrading my RAM is currently not possible (and does not scale too well once I start letting this script loose on larger amounts of files).

My only Idea at the moment is caching on Disk (Which will slow the process down even more), or writing temporary sets to disk and merging them afterwards, which will take even more time and the complexity would be horrible indeed. Is there even a solution that will not result in horrible runtimes?

For the record, this is my full source. As it was written for personal use only, it is pretty horrible, but you get the idea.

```
import os
import sys
words=set([])
lastperc = 0
current = 1
argl = 0
print "Searching for .txt-Files..."
for _,_,f in os.walk("."):
    for file in f:
        if file.endswith(".txt"):
            argl=argl+1
print "Found " + str(argl) + " Files. Beginning parsing process..."
print "0%                                              50%                                             100%"
for r,_,f in os.walk("."):
    for file in f:
        if file.endswith(".txt"):
            fobj = open(os.path.join(r,file),"r")
            for line in fobj:
                line = line.strip()
                word, sep, remains = line.partition(" ")
                if word != "":
                    words.add(word)
                word, sep, remains = remains.partition(" ")
                while sep != "":
                    words.add(word)
                    word, sep, remains2 = remains.partition(" ")
                    remains = remains2
                if remains != "":
                    words.add(remains)
            newperc = int(float(current)/argl*100)
            if newperc-lastperc > 0:
                for i in range(newperc-lastperc):
                    sys.stdout.write("=")
                    sys.stdout.flush()
            lastperc = newperc
            current = current+1
print ""
print "Done. Set contains " + str(len(words)) + " different words. Sorting..."
sorteddic = sorted(words, key=str.lower)
print "Sorted. Writing to File"
print "0%                                              50%                                             100%"
lastperc = 0
current = 1
sdicl = len(sorteddic)-1
fobj = open(sys.argv[1],"w")
for element in sorteddic:
    fobj.write(element+"\n")
    newperc = int(float(current)/sdicl*100)
    if newperc-lastperc > 0:
        for i in range(newperc-lastperc):
            sys.stdout.write("=")
            sys.stdout.flush()
    lastperc = newperc
    current = current+1
print ""
print "Done. Enjoy your wordlist."
```

Thanks for your help and Ideas.

Comment: Your use of `line.partition(" ")` seems like it could be simplified by using a simple `line.split()` ... but I could be missing something.

Comment: @mgilson Yup, looks like it. I screwed that part of the code up, it seems.

Answer (score 3):

You're probably going to need to store the keys on disk. A key-value store like [Redis](http://redis.io/) might fit the bill.

Comment: you could use pickle or sqlite3 also?

Answer (score 2):

Do you really mean 6-10GB of unique words? Is this English text? Surely even counting proper nouns and names there shouldn't be more than a few million unique words.

Anyway, what I would do is process one file at a time, or even one section (say, 100k) of a file at a time, a build a unique wordlist just for that portion. Then just union all the sets as a post-processing step.

Comment: My predictions came from the space used in the first 25 %, it might very well be lower. And, as you can see in the code, at the moment I fail to remove special chars, so "hi", "hi." "hi,", ... will all be counted as unique words, which bloats the dictionary further. Thanks for the idea though, I might do just that.

Answer (score 1):

My inclination is towards a database table, but if you want to stay within a single framework, checkout PyTables: http://www.pytables.org/moin

Answer (score 1):

The first thing I'd try would be to restrict words to lower-case characters – as Tyler Eaves pointed out, this will probably reduce the set size enough to fit into memory.  Here's some very basic code to do this:

```
import os
import fnmatch
import re

def find_files(path, pattern):
    for root, files, directories in os.walk(path):
        for f in fnmatch.filter(files, pattern):
            yield os.path.join(root, f)

words = set()
for file_name in find_files(".", "*.txt"):
    with open(file_name) as f:
        data = f.read()
    words.update(re.findall("\w+", data.lower()))
```

A few more comments:

1. I would usually expect the dictionary to grow rapidly at the beginning; very few new words should be found late in the process, so your extrapolation might severely overestimate the final size of the word list.
2. Sets are very efficient for this purpose.  They are implemented as hash tables, and adding a new word has an amortised complexity of O(1).

Comment: Thanks for your code and observations. Especially the complexity of Sets is very interesting.

Answer (score 0):

Hash your keys into a codespace that is smaller and more managable.  Key the hash to a file containing the keys with that hash. The table of hashes is  much smaller and the individual key files are much smaller.

Comment: Do you have a proposal for a hashing algorithm for this? The average word uses less space than a 32 characters MD5 hash...

Comment: @malexmave: Note that MD5 hashes are 128 bits, so you can store them in 16 bytes.  They are often represented as 32 byte hex strings.  Of course that doesn't change anything about your observation – they won't help you.

Comment: @malexmav My appologies, I wasn't clear,  I meant a non-unique hash, presumeably only enough bits to get your dictionaries down to reasonable size. Multiply words would hash into duplicate codes and thus by stored in the same file.

Comment: F83 and many Forth implementations use a 16bit hash to speed word lookups into the symbol table. It's not a size issue, your not storing the hashes. Its like indexinging into the Ts in phone book but instead of alphabetic your index function is a polynomial. That way your grouping is balanced.

Comment: That might be a way, although I would have to open each dictionary file in the end, remove duplicates, then merge all of them and optionally sort them, which will increase runtime quite a bit (Although I guess I can hardly ask for a solution that does not increase runtime while guaranteeing termination without MemoryError).